# Convert string in floats in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with string columns some of them are numbers in string and some others are just string. I want to convert the columns that are numbers in floats but not string. Someone sent me a link but it works only if you know the column and my dataframe is flexible.

```py
>>> df_1
     A    B      C
2    M01  test   '100.0'
3    M02  test2  '80.0'
```

[Convert a string that contains a price with space after thousands to float in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147208/convert-a-string-that-contains-a-price-with-space-after-thousands-to-float-in-pa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
>>> data = {'A': {2: 'M01', 3: 'M02'},
            'B': {2: 'test', 3: 'test2'},
            'C': {2: '100.0', 3: '80.0'}}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.dtypes
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
>>> df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
>>> df.dtypes
A     object
B     object
C    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':['M01', 'M02'],'B':['test','test2'], 'C': ['100.0', '80.0']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#find columns which are numbers  
m = df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull().all())

#convert True columns in `m` to float
for col in df.columns:
    if m[col]:
        df[col] = df[col].astype({col: 'float'})

df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
A     object
B     object
C    float64
dtype: object
```